# Navigate UL alphabetically like a select

Tags: jquery

I've got the following code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="init">[SELECT]</li>
   <li data-value="value 1">Andorra</li>
    <li data-value="value 2">Bulgaria</li>
    <li data-value="value 3">Germany</li>
    <li data-value="value 3">Finland</li>
    <li data-value="value 3">Nigeria</li>
    <li data-value="value 3">Uganda</li>
    <li data-value="value 3">Iceland</li>
</ul>
```

View it all in a fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/vasiev89/tekLkqm7/

I have a list of countries. I would like to be able to navigate through this list in the same way one would navigate a select dropdown **natively**.

Any suggestions which do not include filtering? All countries need to be visible. Ideally, when a user types in a letter - the selected state would go to the first element which it finds in the set of matched elements.

What I tried:
 filter - that works but filters out Countries which do not equal the text inputted - this is not desirable.

My personal preference would be a select option dropdown. However, options do not allow styling and I need a country flag next to each list item as well as custom fonts and colours, hence the UI-LI route taken.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Why not use an autocomplete plugin? There are lots already available which have the exact functionality you require

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - true, there are but I was looking for a light-weight solution which wouldn't involve a third party script